# Last-Hit Challenge: How do I increase the duration?

Tags: dota-2

This is more of a technical question than a gameplay question... So here goes:
**How do I increase the duration of which the Last-Hit Challenge Tutorial lasts for in DoTA 2?**

By default, it is set to 10 minutes from the moment you click the "Start [Lane you chose]" button. Is there any way to make that 10 minutes into something longer like 20 minutes?
(Or endless, although setting it to a very high number would achieve the same thing)

Comment: I believe the point of the last hit challenge is so that you can work on your early game last hitting abilities, isn't it? The first 10 minutes are some of the most important minutes of a game of Dota 2 and getting good at making sure you can get your creep score fairly high is important. If you were to play a longer last hit challenge, I'd think that the items and levels you will inevitably get would take away from the challenge.

Comment: I know what you're trying to say... But is there a way to increase the time (or decrease the time)? And that's not answering my question - It's an excuse NOT to answer it.

Comment: Well you could make a custom game with just you and get last hits that way.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm looking at the counter for accuracy... And passive bots don't do anything (but just "be" in the lane) and easy bots aren't as responsive as the bot in the challenge... While hard/insane bots just make last-hitting a problem because they'll focus on you and not the creeps.

Comment: What @Dispensador said, also leveling up makes last-hitting a lot easier (I'm thinking of typical heroes for this challenge like Shadow Fiend for example with almost 3 agi / level, after the 6 min mark it starts making a big difference even without any skills)

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. If you can turn cheats on for a lobby where you are going to play the last hit challenge you could just modify settings while the game is going on. I have never bothered playing this challenge and do not know what options are available to you before you start, and I do not have access to a computer with Dota 2 on it presently.

Comment: Um.. I'm not sure how to actually use the commands... So yeah.. You'll have to help me out in this department... But I do know how to setup a lobby (should be the basics for everyone) with cheats.

Answer (score 1):

As Dispenser already said: **You don't**. **You can't**.

That's the entire point of the exercise, limiting you to 10 minutes forces you to work on what the challenge is for. Giving more time would make the entire challenge pointless, and thus it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I typically just start a bot match and go for 10 min mid against medium or hard bots.  Yeah it might not be as nice, but it's good enough.  You might start checking your 4, 8, and 10 minute marks.

The new 1v1 match making should also give you a place to work on this.

Answer (score -4):

Use this command in lobby with cheats enabled.

> dota_tutorial_start lasthit